# How I can disable MRTK's keyboard shortcut

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am currently working on MRTK and I import an input field to receive type-ins. However, when I press the key w,s,a,d, the camera will move around while I am typing. In the API it says:

Input simulation is enabled by default in the profiles that ship with MRTK. You can simply click Play button to run the scene with input simulation support.

Press W, A, S, D, Q, E keys to move the camera.
To keep simulated hands in the view, press T or Y key

How I can disable these shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, please navigate to Edit → Project Setting → Input Manager, and then modify the `Alt Negative Button` and `Alt Position Button` property under the `Horizontal` and `Vertical` Axes.